# Forking a GitHub wiki?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to download a local copy of [the API documentation for D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference), so that I can more easily search it. Is there a way to do this?

If I hit fork, it just downloads the actual project files.

Comment: Did you click the "git access" link that's right near the top of that page?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
git clone https://github.com/mbostock/d3.wiki.git
```

Comment: ah, thanks. Where does this end up being saved? I followed these instructions here: http://gitref.org/creating/

Comment: In a `d3.wiki` subdirectory of the current directory.

Comment: sorry - this is my first time using git and I suppose I don't get the premise - I can see my repositories online, and I can access them using the terminal, although that is extremely confusing to me - but is there some sort of publicly accessible url for this? If I use https://github.com/heaversm/d3.wiki I get a 404

Comment: @mheavers, I don't follow.  If you want a URL, isn't it just https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference ?  You asked for a local copy, which is what the `clone` command will give you.

Comment: Yes but where can I find that - I can't find it on my hard drive - is it just that it's getting cloned to some hidden directory?

Comment: It's in the directory where you ran that command.  After running it, in the same directory, do `dir`.

Comment: ah - sorry - it was copied into the .ssh directory, which is hidden from mac finder. Thanks for the help.